# get array keys that are still less in value stackup in javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, node.js, logic

i have a problem, im trying to count how many child is age(as key) as below, but we want to 
get the bigkids group(ones that are the big kids in this case is 4 and 2) based on a 
kids >= 4 kids group i want to get the biggest number of age that can make a bigkids group.

**question how can i get the age of the new created group with the biggest age under/same as 4 kids?**

so heres what we get in input

```
max_bigest_kids_in_group = 4
kids object = {
//age 0 have 7 kids
'0' : 7
//age 1 have 3 kids
'1' : 3
//age 2 have 2 kids
'2' : 2 
//age 4 have 1 kids
'4' : 1
//lets say there is no age 3 or 5,6 and so on.
}
```

heres what i have tried and currently made so far currently in psudo

```
try    biggest  next biggest 
    ('4' = 1) + ('2' = 2)  (oke becouse 1+2 is 3 >= 4) save array [4 and 2]
try    biggest  next biggest next biggest
    ('4' = 1) + ('2' = 2) + ('1' = 3) (not oke becouse 1+2+3 is 6 >= 4) stop becouse its more then x = 4
    get array [4 and 2] 

    // expected result is {'4','2'} or ['4','2'] so if max_bigest_kids_in_group = 6 then it will be ['4','2','1']
```

**how can we get that exptected result? in javascript**

ps. sorry if the title is not that accurate, if there is any suggestion please comment or edit.

Comment: Is this a [set cover problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem)?

Comment: wow thanks for the link @Stano let me read it for a sec, never herd it before

Comment: Can you explain with an example?

Comment: Yeah, have it almost done. I hope that [it is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm) what you are looking for. :-)

Comment: yes i know that and i think its right, im trying to make it too, becouse its greedy to get the highest value of the kid age then stackup the value and match it with the max kids in group

Comment: Oh yeah. Or maybe it's this one: [Knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). Now it's many years since I left school.

Comment: nope not that one, because its the biggest right? not get maximum group in age, we don't want a age 0 age being a leader of the other 1 age kids. we want the biggest age in the class to form a group, but not more then 4 kids.

Comment: [Here is one fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalatino/5bzcY/7/) , hope that somebody can finish it correctly.

Comment: it returns `age:1 count:3, age: 4, count 1.` should it be `age: 4 count 1 and age : 2 count 2` so total count is 3 and its also below `max_biggest_kids_in_group = 4 // maximum total count of kids` btw thankyou so much teaching me this much. im currently trying to understand how it work :)

Comment: <strike>found it, `akids.sort(function(a,b){ return a.count-b.count; }); ` seems to be right, but im not so sure if im doing it right. btw it work so far so its accepted, why not give an answer since it is right. well maybe + explain so anybody can see this if they are searching for it. see http://jsfiddle.net/5bzcY/10/ </strike> * edited anyway its still wrong when we put in the `var max_kid_age = 6;` should be enough becouse there are 4 kids right?

Comment: update, `akids.sort(function(a,b){ return b.age-a.age; });` fixed it. i think this time for sure.

Comment: @Stano: No, it is neither a set cover nor a knapsack problem. He just wants to build a sum (with a maximum) and wants to know the keys of the set to achieve this, but the keys are sorted from highest to lowest - nothing to choose.

Comment: @Bergi Oh yeah, now it's clear to me. :) Thanks Bergi for explanation, surely it is it.

Answer (score 2):

That's simple. Just make a loop over the kids, like in your pseudo code.

```
var kids = {
   '0' : 7, //age 0 have 7 kids
   '1' : 3, //age 1 have 3 kids
   '2' : 2, //age 2 have 2 kids
   '4' : 1  //age 4 have 1 kids
};
function getAgesOfOldestKids(n) {
/* get: {number} how many kids */

    // lets begin with some magic to find out the maximum age in the set
    // you might code this with a for-in-loop over kids
    var max = Math.max.apply(null, Object.keys(kids));

    var ages = []; // ages of the kids in the result
    var count = 0; // how many kids are in the set
    for (var i=max; i>=0; i--)
        if (i in kids) { // age level exists
            count += kids[i]; // add number of kids
            if (count > n) // kids in the set are more than allowed
                return ages; // break the loop
            else
                ages.push(i); // add this age step to the result
        }
    return ages; // there may be less children than requested
}

> getAgesOfOldestKids(4)
["4", "2"]

// a trick to get the number of kids in the result:
> var ages = [4, 2];
> ages.reduce(function(n, age){return n+kids[age]}, 0)
3
```

---

other possible and much shorter solution, looping directly over the kids' keys:

```
function getAgesOfOldestKids(n) {
/* get: {number} how many kids */

    // ages, sorted descending
    var ages = Object.keys(kids).sort(function(a,b){return b-a;});

    var count = 0; // how many kids are in the set
    for (var i=0; i<ages.length-1 && count <= n; i++)
        count += kids[ages[i]]; // add number of kids
    return ages.slice(0, i-1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume your object `kids` is not sorted by default. Also, in JS you can't rely on which order the [for…in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop returns the properties (see the link for more details). So the first step is converting your object in a structure that you can sort and be sure the order you obtain is the correct one:

```
kids  = {
    //age 0 have 7 kids
    '0' : 7,
    //age 1 have 3 kids
    '1' : 3,
    //age 2 have 2 kids
    '2' : 2,
    //age 4 have 1 kids
    '4' : 1
    //lets say there is no age 3 or 5,6 and so on.
}

var array = [];

for (var age in kids) {
    if (kids.hasOwnProperty(age)) {
        array.push({age: age, count: kids[age]});
    }
}
```

After you have it, you can sort the array as follow:

```
array.sort(function(a, b) { return a.count - b.count });
```

And then, you can makes your calculation:

```
var maxKids = 4;
var groups = [];
var count = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    count += array[i].count;

    if (count <= maxKids)
        groups.push(array[i].age);
    else
        break;
}

console.log(groups);
```

This approach also covers when all groups of kids exceed the maximum number of kids you can have, so you will obtain an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I quite follow the problem, but, is it something along these lines?

http://jsfiddle.net/kyuff/Tkj2r/7/

```
var kids = {
//age 0 have 7 kids
    0 : 7,
//age 1 have 3 kids
    1 : 3,
//age 2 have 2 kids
    2 : 2,
//age 4 have 1 kids
    4 : 1
    };
function between(min, max) {
    var age = 0;
    for(var age in kids) {
        if( age >= min && age <= max) {
            age += kids[age];
        }
    }
    return age;
}


document.write( between(2,3) );
```

Comment: maybe something like `get_bigest_kids_age(max_bigest_kids_group_count)` the biggest age is '4' and '2' right?, and they have all the condition, '4' only 1 and '2' only 2 where 1+2 is less then max_bigest_kids_group_count. so it returns age '4' and '2'